# Which minimum android version can run chromecast supported video stream app?

Tags: android, video-streaming, chromecast, http-live-streaming, google-cast

I want to add chromecast support in my live stream playback app. I want to know which minimum android version can support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cast is based on Play Services and it is supported all the way back to API 9 (GB).